# Windows 2008 R2 powershell The term 'Get-Disk' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: windows, powershell

I am getting an error when using Get-Disk cmdlet

Windows version: Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 64b

Windows 2008 R2 powershell The term 'Get-Disk' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet. I have version 3 of Powershell

> PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Disk

```
Get-Disk : The term 'Get-Disk' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Disk
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-Disk:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

> PS C:\Windows\system32> $PSVersionTable`

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.16398
PSVersion                      3.0
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Comment: That's weird. Do you get anything when you run `Get-Command -Module Storage` ? If not, try `Import-Module Storage`, and then the first one again. Just to identify if you're missing the module or auto-loading is not working

Comment: module-storage is only available for windows 2012 isnt it ?

Comment: I am not sure if it was only available in 2012. Would have liked to use it on 2008 R2. I upgraded powershell to 3.0 but it still does not work. So assuming it is only supported on 2012 (or Windows 8) and above.

Comment: kayasax seems to be correct: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/10/26/use-powershell-to-create-a-bootable-usb-drive.aspx
good catch =)

Comment: Also tried the 2 commands but no response for "Get-Command -Module Storage" and for the other I get an error back. Import-Module : The specified module 'Storage' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module
directory.

Comment: Hmm thanks Kayasax and Graimer that proves it, Not supported on Windows 2008 R2

Comment: Depending on what you need you can try WMI: `Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk`, `Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive` and `Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume` gives you access to some information

Comment: Graimer I am looking for offline disks. I can do Diskpart and listdisk to see all disks. I am not able to see the using Get-WmiObject

Comment: that's true. `diskpart` with some string-formatting is your only (easy) option for that :)

Comment: Using diskpart with "select disk 1 \n ATTRIBUTES DISK CLEAR READONLY \n online disk \n CONVERT MBR \n clean \n create partition primary \n assign letter=E \n active \n format fs=ntfs label=E Drive". Calling it as: DiskPart /s C:\DiskPartScript.txt

Answer (score 7):

[Just combining the comments into an answer and added a bit]

I also was looking to use the `Get-Disk` command on an Azure VM Server 2008 R2, I installed PowerShell 3.0 and `Get-Disk` was still not available, and then googled to this page.

From this [Scripting Guy blog link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/10/26/use-powershell-to-create-a-bootable-usb-drive.aspx) it mentions that

> Note   The version of Windows PowerShell 3.0 for Windows 7 does not
>   contain the Storage module at this time, so Windows 8 or Windows
>   Server 2012 is a requirement.

So if your looking to use `Get-Disk` on Windows Server 2008 R2, you cant.

The same Scripting Guy link also provides the relevant DiskPart commands that can be used instead.

```
From an elevated shell:

    DiskPart.exe
    List disk
    Select disk 1—disk 1 being the USB drive
    Clean
    Create partition primary
    Select partition 1—partition 1 being the new partition
    Active
    Format FS=NTFS
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your use case, note that you can also get information on the disk in powershell without using a cmdlet, using the [Win32_Volume class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) For example, you could do the following to change the drive letter:

```
$drive = gwmi win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'F:'"
$drive.DriveLetter = "D:"
$drive.Put()
```